# The maximum number of users who have logged in to the Oracle Database

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Is there any variable or view in the Oracle Database 12 that stores the maximum number of users who have logged in at the same time (for example since the last restart)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [system view `V$RESOURCE_LIMIT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_2128.htm#REFRN30206) for the `MAX_UTILIZATION` of resource called `SESSIONS`:

```
SELECT MAX_UTILIZATION FROM V$RESOURCE_LIMIT WHERE RESOURCE_NAME = 'SESSIONS'
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams220.htm#REFRN10197):

> `SESSIONS` specifies the maximum number of sessions that can be created in the system. Because every login requires a session, this parameter effectively determines the maximum number of concurrent users in the system.

`MAX_UTILIZATION` is like a high-water mark that shows the maximum value that the parameter reached. It is reset everytime the instance restarts.

Comment: MAX_UTILIZATION shows a lot more than there are user accounts in the database. CURRENT_UTILIZATION shows (now) about 50 when no one else is logged in except me.

Comment: @GMB: Maybe it also shows background processes in addition to logged in users? From the same documentation you mentioned " You should always set this parameter explicitly to a value equivalent to your estimate of the maximum number of concurrent users, plus the number of background processes, plus approximately 10% for recursive sessions." That would explain such high values.

Comment: @RobertDrygas: possibly... Which result do you get when you do `select count(*) from v$session`?

Comment: @RobertDrygas: when it comes to `MAX_UTILIZATION`, it may be more that the number of database accounts, since a given user may open more than one concurrent session.

Comment: Comparing... current_utilization of sessions from v$resource_limit is 191; count(username) from v$sessions (without null usernames) is 141; count(distinct usename) from v$sessions (without null usernames) is 48 - 'distinct' is for you wrote, a user may open more than one concurrent session.